# Using and Communicating with Directive from different Controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I would like to create a directive that is similar to a control. It should be able to be instantiated from "anywhere" and I want to call functions on it's scope from a parent scope/controller.

A very easy example would be:

I have a special directive called myContactForm (which can be used in different places and pages). Now this myContactForm, in it's templace, uses the directive myEditControl. myEditControl is, when you look at the template nothing but an input and a button and in the scope has the function "clear()" so you can delete whatever is inside the input and maybe other functions.

Now when something happens in myContactForm (for example a button is pressed or a broadcast is received or whatever) I want to call "clear()" on the myEditControl that's inside it. Just like it was a normal control.

**How would that be done?**

I know about the require but that only works for parents and I would have to know the Controllername of the Directive that uses myEditControl. Instead I want any View/Controller to be able to use myEditControl. And I cannot require the myEditControl-Controller from myContactForm because it is a child not a parent.

**What is the technique used in angular to solve these kind of problems?**

My idea was to transmit a callback or "myContactForm"-Scope to the myEditControl with an attribute so the myEditControl can "register" itself on the parent and the parent then saves that controls scope for later reference and calling of functions. This seems very hacky though....

Comment: You should not. It's an anti-pattern. If you insist on doing this then read about `$scope.$emit` and `$scope.$broadcast`.

Comment: if it is an anti-pattern: could you give me a solution? Hence my questions "How would that be done?" and "What is the technique used in angular to solve these kind of problems?". I don't insist on doing this if there is an alternative!

Comment: You'd define a `$scope.clear` function on `myContactForm`. Then you'd pass it to `myEditControl`'s scope (`scope: {parentClear: '=clear'}`). Then in the `$scope.clear` function of `myEditControl` you'd also call `$scope.parentClear` which is the one defined in `myContactForm`. That way the directives are not coupled in any way, the only requirement being that `myEditControl` _requires_ a `clear` function in the parent scope. And it does not need to _require_ it. You can check if it's not `undefined` and call it only if it's not (`scope: {parentClear: '=?clear'}`).

Comment: well I need it the other way round, I wanna call `myEditControl`'s clear-Function from `myContactForm` because myContactForm decides to clear the edit.

Comment: Then it's a clear case of `$scope.$broadcast` and `$scope.$on`. I was under the impression that you need to do it the other way around. Sorry :)

Comment: okay - if that's the way to do it in angular: thanks! :)